# Issues authenticate Google via Curl

Tags: php, curl, google-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate on Google using curl.

I get credentials on the Google Console Developers. 
 I still don't understand what I have to do, what url I have to curl.

Do you know some docs or tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try the google api client library. You can find it here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: I just have another question if you can help me

Comment: whats your question?